# Referencing file contents in a switch case statement in C#/Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, file-handling, case-statement

I'm setting up a menu system whereby a user is asked to pick a radio station from a list, and for ease of use down the road, I want that list to be in a file called StationList. That bit's all sorted, but I have a problem with the selection process.

Is there a way to have a case statement reference StationList for valid cases instead of having to type them all in manually? I've had a look around and there doesn't seem to be an immediate answer: bear in mind though that I've only been learning it for two weeks :)

Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
i = (an element from iterating through StationList)

switch (selection)
{
case (i):
    i = (int)Choice.GoodChoice;
    Console.WriteLine("You chose " + selection + " radio!");
    break;
case "!exit":
case "!!":
    i = (int)Choice.ExitChoice;
    break;
case "!info":
    TitleScreen();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    break;
default:
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection! Please try again!");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info about exactly what you're trying to do in the case statement?

Comment: Have added some code: hope it roughly demonstrates what I'm trying to do. 'selection' is data entered by the user... having asked the question, it would seem the best way to go about it would be to have the case statement loop with 'i' changing on each loop... seems a bit wasteful though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible.

Event if it *were* possible, imagine that you have your switch with cases automatically -- how would you define what to do in each of the `case`s?

Edit:
You need just to be able to check if the selection is one of the strings from the list. So you need basically (1) add all your strings to a `HashSet`, (2) you code will be like that:

```
HashSet hashset = new HashSet();
using (var file = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        hashset.Add(line);
}
// ...

if (hashset.Contains(selection))
{
    i = (int)Choice.GoodChoice;
    Console.WriteLine("You chose " + selection + " radio!");
}
else
{
    switch (selection)
    {
    case "!exit":
    case "!!":
        i = (int)Choice.ExitChoice;
        break;
    case "!info":
        TitleScreen();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection! Please try again!");
        break;
    }
}
```